# How to structure an ecommerce microservice application

Tags: node.js, microservices, e-commerce, event-sourcing

I thinking about building a micro-services eCommerce multi-vendor from scratch. The idea is to let any client create an account and can connect their own website or mobile app. I thinking about doing it an opensource project if I make a good start so if you interested to participate let me know.

So I tried to imagine a structure, but I am not sure about how to structure the database.

Let's say I have client send me a request like that:

```js
{ 
    user_id: "123",
    products: [
      {
        product_id: 1, 
        quantity: 2, 
        price: 20, currency: "EUR" 
      }
      // etc...
   ],
   timestamp: 90428092094,
   action: "saveEvent",
}

// actions :
// 1 => saveEvent (the above object)
// 2 => saveOrder to "service order"
// 3 => updateInventory to "service inventory"
// etc...
// then return response to client
```

Here the starter :
[image]

Am I in a good direction with this structure ?

Thanks for your help.

Nico

Comment: Unrelated to the design question, but I would not accept the price to pay from the client. They could send any amount, really.

Comment: Yes sure, the price value should not be here. I have not started yet I just try to understand the concept. What about the design, looks good ?

Comment: It's not clear enough for me to answer. In particular, the "Event-management" layer is something I am do not completely understand. Perhaps you can amend your question to write out the layers and the responsibilities of each.

Comment: The event manager will 1/ register every event -  2/ Communicate with every microservice